# Cannot import enum into nuxt.config.ts

Tags: nuxtjs3

When I try to import this enum:

```
// in /contants/environments.ts

enum ENV {
    DEVELOPMENT = 'development',
    PRODUCTION = 'production',
}
export default ENV;
```

into my nuxt.config.ts, I get this error when starting nuxt dev:

```
ERROR  Cannot find module '~/constants/environments'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Require stack:
- C:\dev\project\nuxt.config.ts
```

What am I doing wrong? This works with Nuxt2

Comment: Typo `/conStants/environments.ts`?

Comment: I deleted my comment - the error still happens every time I execute yarn (add, dev...) 

Comment: Could it be that the alias `~` is not created until the nuxt.config.ts is executed? So would a relative path work?

Comment: @David sorry for the late reply. You were right, that was it. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the alias `~` is not created until the nuxt.config.ts is executed. Can you try a relative path?

e.g.: `'./constants/environments'`